# how to call SettingsApi in a cordova application

Tags: android, cordova

As per the android developer documentation https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi

it says `GoogleApiClient` can be invoked inside onCreate and by using that GPS can be enabled when application launches

How to do this in a `cordova application`?

Currently I am trying to do with a basic cordova application

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this) 
         .....
         googleApiClient.connect();
    }
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
         LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
         .....
         LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

         builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
         PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());

         result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
           @Override 
           public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
           }
         });
    }
}
```

But while launching the application nothing happens

I want the `Use Location?` dialogue box to be appearing

Answer (score 1):

You could use [cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy) to request high accuracy location mode (i.e. GPS) when the app starts. It uses the Google Play Services Location API (v7+) to check/change the device location settings. If the current device location setting is less accurate than the requested level (or off entirely), the native dialog will prompt the user and if they accept, GPS will be switched on.

In case the user doesn't have an up-to-date version of Google Play Services or there's some other problem accessing it, you may want to use [cordova.plugins.diagnostic](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) as a fallback and show the location settings page so the user can enable GPS manually.

Note that Cordova apps generally don't make use of the native onCreate, because this is often invoked before the Cordova WebView has been instantiated and therefore before the "app" logic exists. Instead, it can be invoked on Cordova's [`deviceready`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.0.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html) event, which is fired when the Cordova environment setup is complete.

Example usage:

```
function onRequestSuccess(success){
    console.log("Successfully set requested accuracy: "+success.message);
}

function onRequestFailure(error){
    console.error("Accuracy request failed: error code="+error.code+"; error message="+error.message);
    if(error.code === cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.ERROR_USER_DISAGREED){
        // User disagreed so exit the app
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    }else{
        if(window.confirm("Failed to automatically set Location Mode to 'High Accuracy'. Would you like to switch to the Location Settings page and do this manually?")){
            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.request(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFailure, cordova.plugins.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}, false);
```

[image: cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy example screencapture]

Comment: But if the user does not choose **yes** then I should close the app and should not allow the user to use the app

Comment: ok, I will test, but still this happens only after the html is rendered and device ready is triggered, so I may not agree to this solution

Answer (score 0):

This is easier than you are trying.

Cordova has their own API for geolocalization.

Just add the permissions in config and android.xml

app/res/xml/config.xml

```
<plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
```

app/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

And call the API

```
geolocation.getCurrentPosition
geolocation.watchPosition
geolocation.clearWatch
```

Documentation:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova/geolocation/geolocation.html

EDIT:

It looks like exists a plugin which does what you want

https://github.com/rodrigo-martinezd/cordova-dialog-gps[enter link description here](https://github.com/rodrigo-martinezd/cordova-dialog-gps)

Post your result, as I haven't tested it ;)

Comment: I am able to get location and render a map all those things, I want the application to ask a question to enable GPS if the GPS is disabled whenever the application is launched

Comment: Just use this methods. In getCurrentPosition, you get error callback if the GPS is disabled. In this case, just open an alert asking the user to enable it. Is this the behaviour that you want? I dont think that the app can enable the GPS by itself if the user have disabled it manually.

Comment: making an alert asking the user to enable it is not I want, I want the Settings API to be invoked and ask like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/lofGl.png this is a native dialog box newly introduced in google play services

Comment: I went through that, as per the code it is only using AlertDialog.Builder which means it will only display a native dialog box, but in my case the GPS itself will be enabled when I repond to the dialog box

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want - https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy - I was looking for the same stuff when I ran into your question on here!

Comment: My bad, didn't refresh the page before posting mine. Cheers!